# How can I change default VB script editor

Tags: windows, script, ide, visual-basic

How can I change the default VB script editor in Windows? Is this possible?

Comment: Options will vary slightly depending on the version of windows you are using. In XP and before, you can actually edit the context menu via explorer and create an Edit option (if it isn't already there) and then assign it to the editor of your choice. If Edit is there, it probably opens in Notepad by default. In Vista and later you will need to manually edit this in the registry (something like HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.vbs). I just don't know off-hand exactly what you need to add, but it is a folder structure that will allow you to specify different options and actions for those options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stored in the registry under this key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Edit\Command
```

Create or edit the default REG_EXPAND_SZ value.  The default is to open in notepad.exe with the following command line.

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\Notepad.exe" %1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any default VBScript editor in windows as it is editable in any Editor , i myself use Notepad++ for VB Scripting,

But If you really want to change the Default editor just Right-Click the vbs file , choose Open with -> Default Program , select the Editor you wanna use and tick mark the 'Always use the selected program to open this kind of File'

but doing this will execute the vbs file in an editor and it won't be executed as a normal VB Script.

Comment: This isn't changing the default editor, this is changing the default application...and for a vbs file, this really isn't going to be the best option.

Comment: If you revised your question to explain how to change the **edit** action for .vbs, it would be a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Nilpo is correct, and the string should be changed to

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" %1

to change the right-click "Edit" association to Notepad++

Comment: Welcome to superuser, I don't see how this improves Nilpo's answer. He is using the system bundled `notepad` and you the freeware `notepad++`. But the method stays the same, or not?